# Make img grow to max width/height regardless of container and maintain aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have an `<img>` which is positioned absolutely within a `<div>`. The `<div>` is 100px by 100px.
The `<img>`, when clicked, should grow to a known max width or height, say 500px by 700px. If the `<img>` is smaller, say 300px by 250px, then that's as large as it should get. Aspect ratio should be maintained.

Setting height and width to 100% just makes the `<img>` the size of the containing `<div>`.

I'm looking for either a css or vanilla javascript solution. (I don't require the code for a click animation, just a static end result so I can apply the concept)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the max-width of the image as 100%.
Height should be set to auto.

**Solution 1** : When the image can grow up to its parent div's width:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
}
.wrapper img {
  /*width:100%;*/
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">

</div>
```

**Solution 2** : Initially the image width will be restricted by the max-width property to stay within the thumbnail size.

Onclick of image, remove the thumbnail class, so that it naturally over flows the parent to its original size

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}
.wrapper img.thumbnail {
  /*width:100%;*/
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  Initially
  <img class="thumbnail" src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">

</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  On click
  <img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">

</div>
```

Comment: But isn't it possible a max-width of 100% would exceed my known/desired max-width of 500px ?

Comment: If the image size is greater than 500px, then the image would automatically resize to fit within the parent

Comment: @KacyRaye Same code sample with smaller wrapper https://jsfiddle.net/jp3fsqv9/ . Hope this clarifies your doubt

Comment: But in my question I said I want it to grow to a desired max-width/height regardless of how large the container is.  *the image would automatically resize to fit within the parent*.  That's exactly what I do not want to happen.

Comment: When you say if the image is smaller "If the <img> is smaller, say 300px by 250px" you didn't compare that with the div container size ?

Comment: Then no code is required at all. Another code snippet will come through in a min

Comment: That 2nd solution is basically what I was looking for, thank you! To make it perfect, I would just have to add `max-width` and `max-height` properties with my desired values for the on-click scenario.